# Python: "import as" Keyword Error

Tags: python, module, pypdf

I've been using Python and I'm importing the PyPDF2 module. I've actually figured how to make my problem work but I would like to know why my previous code was not working.

Here is the old code:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger as merger, PdfFileReader 

def MakeOne(filesList):


    for file in filesList:
        merger().append((file))
    merger().write("AllInOne.pdf")

    print("File AllInOne.pdf has been created")
```

This is the current code which now works.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader
def MakeOne(filesList):

    merger = PdfFileMerger()
    for file in filesList:
        merger.append((file))

    merger.write("AllInOne.pdf")

    print("File AllInOne.pdf has been created")
```

The first piece of code did not crash the console - in fact it did create a file. The only problem was that the file it created was not openable and  was only 1 KB large. The second piece of code is similar to how many people have used this module in StackOverflow and it works perfectly. My question is: why did the first piece of code not provide me with the expected result given that I seemingly worked with "merger" correctly after importing PdfFileMerger as merger?

Thank you for any help provided!

Comment: Every `merger()` call makes a new `PdfFileMerger`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the previous comment notes, every time you call `merger()`, you're creating a new `PdfFileMerger` object. So, when you call `merger().write("AllInOne.pdf")`, you are writing a PDF which has no appended files.

When you use `import <module> as`, you are ''aliasing'' the imported module. So your first code block is exactly the same as the following:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader 

def MakeOne(filesList):


    for file in filesList:
        PdfFileMerger().append((file))
    PdfFileMerger().write("AllInOne.pdf")

    print("File AllInOne.pdf has been created")
```